# Request parameters not coming in facebook webhook callback url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I want to integrate Facebook leads into my WordPress website.

I went through all instructions given on Facebook url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/quickstart/webhooks-integration

But I'm not getting request parameters when webhook trying to verify webhook on page subscription.

```
$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token']
```

Also request body is blank.

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Thanks to help in advance.

Comment: Suggest you go check your server access log to verify what requests exactly Facebook is sending to your endpoint.

Comment: _“But I'm not getting request parameters”_ - and how exactly have you verified/noticed that?

Comment: When I'm verifying from graph explorer tool by passing below data- object, callback_url, verify_token. I'm creating log file on each request

Comment: Huh, what does Graph API Explorer have to do with that? GAE is for _you_ to make requests _to_ the Facebook API.

Comment: exported data of graph api explorer - curl -i -X POST \
 -d "object=page" \
 -d "callback_url=https%3A%2F%2Ffisherzucker.com%2Ffb%2Fwebhook.php" \
 -d "verify_token=abc123" \
 -d "access_token=147121932016159%7CGFeANjmFm5koz81ifuJmGEO7Idk" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/147121932016159/subscriptions"

Comment: That is only the initial subscription part, that is the request you send to Facebook. I asked you about the request that Facebook then makes from their servers to your endpoint ...

Comment: Facebook verify webhook on this initial subscription. Facebook visit webhook url but expected parameters hub_challenge and hub_verify_token not received on webhook page

Comment: Again: Check your server access log to see what request Facebook actually sends.